# Android - determine the charging voltage

Tags: android, usb

I want to find out the value of the charging voltage for my Android device. Is there a way in Android to somehow get this value programmatically?

Comment: I have never come across a device that wasn't 5v...

Comment: @FoamyGuy You could put Android on a wide spectrum of devices, so it is conceivable that the device wouldn't be 5v.

Comment: It would be possible yes. I don't think that information is exposed via any public APIs (I'm not even certain the OS has that info to give actually). If I had to guess where it might be if it does exist I'd start with Build, Environment, or PowerManager.

Comment: well... the old mighty PCs have this information somewhere in BIOS

Comment: I'm not sure what good that information would do you at the software level.  What is your use case for knowing the charging voltage.

That said, I'm pretty sure there's no standard way to get that information. I've worked on devices that made it available via the /proc or /sys interfaces, but it's highly device-specific, and probably implemented on only a very small minority of devices.

Answer (score 1):

The USB voltage specification is nominally 5 volts. If you monitor the voltage manually the current available to the device can vary from 5.5 volts down to 4.5 volts depending on the charger and cable wire diameter and length.

I presume that the internal charge control chipset watches the voltage available and resistance across the wiring to limit the possible current it can pull from the line.

As far as I know, this information does not exist in the android source.

Comment: Yes it does - the answer says " this information does not exist in the android source." it might be wrong but it _is_ an answer.